# How to get and use value on prompt displayed from return statement of window.onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever the page gets refreshed or unloaded,the window.onbeforeunload event is triggered.Whenever this event is triggered,it gives a confirmation/alert box.On this confirmation/alert box ,we have two options "leave this page" and "stay on this page".I want to perform different actions when any these two buttons/options is clicked.How can i do this/capture clicking of these buttons?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body >


    <p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>

    <script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {

        return "Do yoy want to Quit?";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can't. You *could* set a timer to, say, 30 seconds in the future, then react if the timer is still able to tick. That *may* not work if the user waits for more than 30 seconds before dismissing the confirmation message, though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion of Frederic, I wanted to test the timer, and the result is: you can check if the user remains on the page, but you can't check if he comes out and intercept the event. The timer starts when you make a choice, then the timer is useful to give the time to the browser to load the new page (if you close your browser, is immediate and time is relative). But if the timer runs out, you have the answer that you want to stay on your page.

Tested on Chrome, for others must be tested.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('I\'m still here !');
    },5000);
    return "Do yoy want to Quit?";
}
```

I hope it help you.